# Output from arbitrary dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, x86, arm, memory-alignment

I fill the memory as follows:

```
char buf[8] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88};
```

And than put the unsigned long pointer in turn on first 5 bytes and output result:

```
char *c_ptr;
unsigned long *u_ptr;

c_ptr = buf;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    u_ptr = (unsigned long *)c_ptr;
    printf("%X\n",*u_ptr);
    c_ptr++;
}
```

When I execute this code on my x64 plaform I get what I expected:

```
44332211
55443322
66554433
77665544
88776655
```

But when I execute the same code on ARM platform I get following:

```
44332211
11443322
22114433
33221144
88776655
```

I.e. it get bound every 4 byte and dereference only 4 bytes within this bounds.

So I want to ask, if this behavior (when `pointer_value%4 != 0`) erroneous or implementation-specific?

UPD:
I known about endiannes, I want to know is this correct, that I am getting

```
11443322
```

instead of

```
55443322
```

I.e when I have pointer for example `0x10000001`
It makes unsigned long from bytes with addresses `0x10000001`, `0x10000002`, `0x10000003` and than `0x10000000`, instead of `0x10000005`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: So far, every comment and answer has missed the point. The bytes aren't reversed, they're rotated.

Comment: The accepted answer explains what's happening. At the language level I think the problem is that your program is not a valid program according to the standard and you are in the _undefined behavior_ arena: I think converting a `char*` to a `long*` is valid only if the pointer was originaly a pointer to `long*`, problem is that I cannot find the actual standard chapter(s) that make it so.

Comment: The above casting is only way to create a non-aligment pointer. I had problem in a program, where another non-aligment pointer was used, so want to know, is this problem because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After suspecting memory alignment I did a quick google =)

http://awayitworks.blogspot.co.nz/2010/02/arm-memory-alignment.html

Stated in that article:

> Till ARMv4 architecture, it’s assumed that address given for fetching
>   contents is memory aligned...a 32-bit data fetch should have address
>   aligned to 32-bit and so on. As guessed correctly the problem is only
>   for 32-bit and 16-bit data fetching. ARM ignores lower 2-bits of
>   address if the data fetch is 32-bit, and ignores lower 1-bit if data
>   fetch is 16-bit. So, in all if the address is not properly aligned
>   then data fetch will be erroneous.

Note the last sentence =)

If you require the behaviour that you expected on x86, you'll have to explicitly build the integers from chars, *ie* (assuming little-endian):

```
// Endian-specific
inline unsigned long ulong_at( const char *p ) {
    return ((unsigned long)p[0])
         | (((unsigned long)p[1]) << 8)
         | (((unsigned long)p[2]) << 16)
         | (((unsigned long)p[3]) << 24);
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
// Architecture-specific
inline unsigned long ulong_at( const char *p ) {
    unsigned long val;
    char *v = (char*)&val;
    v[0] = p[0];
    v[1] = p[1];
    v[2] = p[2];
    v[3] = p[3];
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I want to know.

Comment: No worries.  Have edited to include some code that should give the behaviour you were hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch a four-byte word from memory, the address should be a multiple of four.

Misaligned access is generally a bad idea on any architecture. Some will throw a SEGFAULT, others will transparently handle the fault and — very slowly — synthesise the correct value by fetching the two words containing the desired value and stitching them together. It appears (though I'm not an expert) that ARM is fetching the four-byte slot that the pointer occupies and rotating the result so that the LSB of the register matches the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Endianness doesn't explain this behavior.  It seems the ARM processor doesn't allow four-byte memory accesses not aligned a four-byte boundary, and the output indicates that the processor read the memory as though it was subjected to a [rightward bitwise rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_no_carry) of 8 bits per byte accessed past the four-byte boundary.  See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for more information on memory alignment.

In fact, on some architectures, a [bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) may occur if you attempt to perform an unaligned memory access of this kind.

Comment: Endianness does not explain the output that the OP has provided.

Comment: ARM processors are little-endian by default BTW.

Comment: Well, sort of. Endianness is about how the processor **stores** and **reads** multi-byte values. Yes, you can pun between byte sequences and larger integral types, but the processor doesn't **change** the order of the bytes that it reads.

Comment: @DragonLord: A large proportion of down-votes are drive-by shootings; asking for their removal is usually pointless. Rather than inverting your answer — which makes nonsense of the comment trail — it's better to delete it and (if you still want to) add another answer.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: The first comment has been flagged as obsolete to address this problem.

Comment: @DragonLord: The comment trail still makes no sense. It's not a big deal; you can leave the question as-is. I was offering advice (which still stands) for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are dereferencing a non-aligned pointer, which, depending on the hardware, may be undefined. Many architectures assume that a `long*` will be aligned to 32 bits of memory, that is, be divisible by 4. If it is not, the result is undefined.

In general, C doesn't guarantee what happens when you cast one pointer type to another.

Comment: Thank you for answer, didn't think that aligment can be a problem.