# Why is pointer arithmetic inconsistent across architectures?

Tags: c, pointers, x86, arm, byte

Given the following code:

```
unsigned char *packet_data = (unsigned char *)malloc(7);
memset(packet_data, 0, 7);

uint16_t crc = 0xa8a9;

*((uint16_t *)&packet_data[5]) = (crc >> 8) | (crc << 8);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", packet_data[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

On my Mac (x86_64), the output is, as expected, **00 00 00 00 00 A8 A9** (A8 goes in byte 5 (counting from 0)). Compiled with clang (LLVM 7.3.0)

On an armv5tejl machine, the output is, however, **00 00 00 00 A8 A9 00** (A8 goes in byte 4 (counting from 0)). In this case, if we switch `5` to `4` on the source code the exact same output will come out. Compiled with gcc 4.6.3, [like this on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A%0A++unsigned+char+*packet_data+%3D+(unsigned+char+*)malloc(7)%3B%0A++memset(packet_data,+0,+7)%3B%0A%0A++uint16_t+crc+%3D+0xa8a9%3B%0A%0A++*((uint16_t+*)%26packet_data%5B5%5D)+%3D+(crc+%3E%3E+8)+%7C+(crc+%3C%3C+8)%3B%0A%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+7%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%2502X+%22,+packet_data%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++%7D%0A++printf(%22%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg463,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu99+-Wall+-Wextra+-O2++-fverbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+4.6.3',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:84.06862745098039,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+4.6.3',t:'0')),l:'4',m:15.931372549019606,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Both machines are little endian.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It's UB so it's UB. When alignment is violated, among all the bad things that can happen (like computer starting to burn and things blowing up), three most likely outcomes are: 1) code works as expected, temporarily, usually with a performance penalty, as certain platforms can handle unaligned access, 2) address is rounded down, because certain platforms "assume aligned" by ignoring lower bits of the pointer , 3) a signal is raised to report alignment violation, OS terminates offending process.

Comment: answer to your specific case: because older ARM versions have the funky behaviour of using the low 2 bits of an address as a rotation count.  See the duplicate.  Unaligned loads on x86 Just Work(tm).  On SPARC, they fault.

Comment: @PeterCordes You incorrectly closed as a duplicate. This question has a C tag. The dup had only a C++ tag.

Comment: @2501: it's an ARM unaligned-access question, not really a C vs. C++ question.  The only explanation I see for the OP's observation is that their ARMv5 must be rotating data for unaligned pointers.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is a C question, while being specific about certain systems. The dup language tags must be consistent.

Comment: @2501: says who?  Vote to reopen if you want, and/or find / write something on meta about it.  Or I'll just retag the dup target, since it's written using the common subset of C and C++ (with printf).

Comment: @PeterCordes Me. I did reopen as the dup was incorrect. Retagging another question with the intention that one would fit as a dup is malicious behavior and I will flag and report such actions.

Comment: @2501: What I meant was, can you cite any sources other than yourself?  It's a question about something that's UB (or implementation defined) in both languages, so I don't see the distinction as important.  I already *added* ARM and a couple other tags (without removing any of the original tags), since it was under-tagged.  I think the tags I chose are more appropriate than also adding a C, and agree that removing C++ wouldn't be good.  If there was room, I'd also add C, since the question and answers are all consistent with that, and if anything it would help people find it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Adding C would be incorrect because the asker choose a specific language, in that case C++. Changing that would change the question.

Comment: @Matoe: you'll find an exact description of what's happening on ARM on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451230/output-from-arbitrary-dereferenced-pointer.  @ 2501 unliked it as a duplicate because C and C++ are different languages, even though in this case they're behaving identically.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well now you're simply lying. I never said it wasn't useful, I only removed it as a dup because it isn't a dup, according to rules of SO. I was never against posting it in the comments, actually I encourage that. Furthermore you could have posted an answer here.

Comment: @2501: yes, sorry, I edited my prev comment.  I was annoyed with your blanket application of rules without regard for cases when it *is* appropriate for a C question to be a dup of a C++ question.  This is nothing like what's discussed on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270527/should-we-discourage-marking-c-and-c-questions-as-duplicates-of-each-other-and, since like I said the behaviour the OP is most interested in is the ARM aspect, not really anything to do with C or C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes Consensus agrees with my position: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194297/is-it-reasonable-to-add-c-tag-to-questions-tagged-with-c

Comment: @2501: right, adding a C tag to the other question is probably a bad idea, although could maybe be justified in this specific case.  But I haven't yet found anything saying that you can't close a C question as a duplicate of a C++ question, when you've looked at both to make sure they really are compatible. (That's definitely true in this case: the OP seems to be hoping for a more arch-specific answer than UB, although it is useful to point out exactly why it is UB, and that even creating an unaligned pointer without dereferencing it is UB in ISO C, even though many implementations define it.)

Comment: There are architectures, where accessing 2 consecutive memory locations by a single instruction with the memory operand containing an odd-valued address transform not into accesses to `address` and `address+1` or `address&~1` and `(address&~1)+1`, but to `address` and `address^1`. This simplifies address calculation. Inverting one bit is cheaper than incrementing the entire address. Setting or resetting a bit is also cheap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming alignment requirement for the type uint16_t is 2, then your code has undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>, as this pointer: `(uint16_t *)&packet_data[5]` isn't correctly aligned.

If you use an aligned offset, like 4, the results should be the same as the behavior is defined.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.3.2.3 Pointers 7):
A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined.

Comment: @Matoe Is "undefined behaviour" sufficient, or do you need to know why those particular processors have this particular behaviour?

Comment: (As for the `malloc` observation, I am aware. I just forgot to zero-initialize it on the question. Will edit.)

Comment: @Matoe Did you get consistent results with an aligned offset?

Answer (score 4):

Your top question- why- is because that is how the hardware works.

You were already quoted the C standard, saying that the behavior is undefined, so any result is a valid result out of C.

For more detail, you should check out what assembly instructions you got out of compiling your code.  Note that one C compiler could choose to give you different instructions (and therefore different results) than another.

To specifically answer your question requires that assembly, but what is probably happening is that your code is compiling to a LDR instruction, which rounds your address down to the nearest 2-byte (even) address.  This is under the ARM5 documents for address alignment.  An online reference I can find is: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1359731171041.html

Based on that specification, an operation on [0] or [1] should both map to an operation on [0], an operation on [2] or [3] should both yield an operation on [2], an operation on [4] or [5] should both yield an operation on [4], and so on.  If you were to work with 32 bit values instead, it should be rounded down to the nearest address divisible by 4.

Note that the C compiler could compile the code to something entirely different, yielding different behavior, and still be within spec, even from one compile to the next.

So while the C result is undefined, the results of the compiled instructions are well undefined, and the resultant assembly instructions obey the spec for that specific chip.

Comment: Ah, so the rotate behaviour only happens on loads, not stores.  I realized after posting about rotates that it should have swapped the bytes or something.

Comment: `another C compiler could give you different results`: True but unlikely in practice.  Compilers (or platform ABIs) can and do define what happens in some cases where the C standard says the behaviour is undefined, not just when it says implementation-defined.  I expect that ARM compilers define the behaviour of code like this as actually compiling to a 16-bit store, or equivalent behaviour if the compiler knows what the run-time behaviour of unaligned accesses will be (e.g. combining it with the memset).